4 term exact sequence diagram, surjective map
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{CD}
     0 @>>> a  @>>>b @>>>c@>>> Y@>>> 0 \\
    @.     @VV{f}V  @VV{g}V  @VV{h}V @VV{i}V  @. \\
     0 @>>>d @>>>e @>>>f @>>>X
  \end{CD}
\]
\end{document}

Output of the above diagram is,

I want to change $f,g,i$ into symbol of surjective map like \twoheadrightarrow and delete symbol $f,g,i$.
And $h$ to be '=' and delete $h$.
How can I do that ? Thank you for your help.

It looks like you are probably using the amscd package. (You should always include your preamble in your question so other users don't have to guess what packages you're using.)
I suggest changing to the more modern (and better maintained) tikz-cd package.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
    0\arrow[r] & a\arrow[r]\arrow[d, ->>] & b\arrow[r]\arrow[d, ->>] & c\arrow[r]\arrow[d, equals] & Y\arrow[r]\arrow[d, ->>] & 0\\
    0\arrow[r] & d\arrow[r] & e\arrow[r] & f\arrow[r] & X
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


A version with xy package. I doubt that exist in amscd package double tips for an arrow. In fact the possible arrows are:
@<<< left arrow @>>> right arrow
@AAA up arrow @= horizontal equals
@VVV down arrow @| vertical equals
@. empty arrow.


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
  \xymatrix@R=3pc@C=4pc{
    0\ar[r] & a\ar[r] \ar@{->>}[d] & b\ar[r]\ar@{->>}[d] & c\ar[r]\ar@{=}[d] & Y\ar[r]\ar@{->>}[d] & 0\\
    0\ar[r] & d\ar[r] & e\ar[r] & f\ar[r] & X
  }
\]
\end{document}


